# When should I be setting borders in UIViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've got a UIView that does not fill the whole screen and I would like to add a top border to that view. However, I keep getting the following: [image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
CGFloat thickness = 4.0f;
CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.announcementCard.frame.size.width, thickness);
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

How I know why the border goes off the screen. This is because I put the border on the view inside the UIViews init method. When I do this the `self.announcementCard.frame.size.width` is 1000 and hence why the border goes off the screen. The `self.announcementCard.frame.size.width` has a width and height of 1000. The reason for this is because the UIView hasn't added the constraints to the UIView in its init methods.

Thus, my question is when should I be calling the code I've written above? When will `self.announcementCard.frame.size.width` have its constraints added to it and have its frame updated?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your subviews (or sublayers) in the `viewDidLoad` method. However if you are using the auto-layout keep a reference of your sublayer and update it in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _borderLayer = [CALayer layer];

  [self.view.layer addSublayer:_borderLayer];
}


- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  _borderLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 3);
}
```

Otherwise you can simply `clipsToBounds` the view to avoid the subviews to be visible beyond the bounds.

```
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `init` the graphics isn't made yet. You have to put all your configuration on graphics object in the `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` of the `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

```
viewWillAppear
```

By the time `viewWillAppear` is called, your subviews have been laid out and the frames are valid. Doing frame-based calculations in `viewDidLoad` can often have issues since the frames have not been set.